# How to start a aws worker enviornment activity in elastic beanstalk after ruby application deployment

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I have been trying to find out the best way to run background jobs using Ruby on AWS Elastic beanstalk, I believe that one good solution is using SWF and activity workers. 
Sample give in the aws document to run  sample, you need to execute three scripts from the command line in separate terminal/console windows

```
files:
"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/domain.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      ruby example_worker1.rb s > /var/log/list.log &
      ruby example_worker2.rb  > /var/log/post.log &
      ruby start_workflow.rb 10 > /var/log/successlog.log &
```

But I get the following error messages:

```
ScheduleActivityTaskFailed
ACTIVITY_TYPE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
```